# Why my curl connect_time is always equal to 0?

Tags: php, curl, proxy

I'm trying to test some SOCKS proxy, and when trying to get the "ping" time of this proxy, I'm looking for the variable "connect_time". For HTTP and HTTPS proxy, this seems to working fine, but not for SOCKS (SOCKS4 or SOCKS5) proxy where the connect_time is always equal to 0 (or almost...) !

```
{
"url":"XXX",
"content_type":"text/html",
"http_code":200,
"header_size":178,
"request_size":379,
"filetime":-1,
"ssl_verify_result":0,
"redirect_count":0,
"total_time":4.738683,
"namelookup_time":0.000021,
"connect_time":0.000023,
"pretransfer_time":0.000104,
"size_upload":140,
"size_download":51275,
"speed_download":10820,
"speed_upload":29,
"download_content_length":-1,
"upload_content_length":140,
"starttransfer_time":0.000149,
"redirect_time":0,
"certinfo":{
},
"redirect_url":""
}
```

Here is a piece of my code :

```
$options = array(
        CURLOPT_PROXY          => $proxy->ip.':'.$proxy->port,
        CURLOPT_TIMEOUT        => 30,
        CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 30,
        CURLOPT_HEADER         => false,
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER     => array('Expect:'),
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST     => false,
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER     => false,
        CURLOPT_VERBOSE         => FALSE,
        CURLOPT_USERAGENT         => 'XXX',
);

if ($proxy->type == 'https')
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPPROXYTUNNEL, 1);
elseif ($proxy->type == 'socks4')
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYTYPE, CURLPROXY_SOCKS4);
elseif ($proxy->type == 'socks5')
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYTYPE, CURLPROXY_SOCKS5);
```

When trying to ping (with `ping`...) this proxy from my computer, I've a ping time of about 50ms...

Is there a bug with curl or php ? Do you know can I retrieve the correct ping time ?

Comment: What are your platform details? What OS?

Comment: Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS (GNU/Linux 2.6.32-19-pve x86_64), PHP 5.3.10-1ubuntu3.6 and curl 7.22.0 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.22.0 OpenSSL/1.0.1 zlib/1.2.3.4 libidn/1.23 librtmp/2.3.

Comment: Why don't you measure the traffic using Wireshark or similar?

Comment: It could be a solution to try to learn more, but I finally think there is a bug with Curl...

Answer (score 2):

When using a proxy, the connect time is the time between the first response of the proxy and the end authentication. So basically your authentication process takes about 0.00023 seconds. Which is quite plausible.

I'm not sure if this is the intended way of how cURL should work because it looks like this is only the case when using proxies on cURL.

I'd consider it a bug.

Comment: Authentification takes 0.00023 seconds, and ping time about 60 ms ? I think there is a problem here...

Comment: I know it sounds weird, but i think its a wrong assignment by cURL. You should try it, just for the heck of it. I've managed to come up with the same 'weird' result on Windows, osx and ubuntu linux. They all had the same weird connect time when using socks proxy